# using <In> tag in CAML Query sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, caml

I am using below CAML query but when I run,it returns all data from document library instead of only corresponding to the < Values> specified in the query

```
<Query>
<Where>
<In>
 <FieldRef Name='Entity_x0020_Served' />
<Values>
 <Value Type='Text'>Payment Solutions</Value>
 <Value Type='Text'>Third Party Processor</Value>
</Values>
</In>
</Where>
</Query>
```

Am I missing anything in this? 
Thanks,
Rushikesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**strong text**Such syntax would not work in SharePoint 2007, you would have to make it `or(equals "Payment Solutions", equals "Third Party Processor")`. Maybe something has changed in SPS2010, but I'd rather suggest you rewrite it in this form.

AND you don't add the `Query` element to your queries!

```
<Where> 
 <Or> 
  <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='Entity_x0020_Served' /> 
     <Value Type='Text'>Payment Solutions</Value> 
  </Eq>
  <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='Entity_x0020_Served' /> 
     <Value Type='Text'>Third Party Processor</Value> 
  </Eq>
</Or> 
</Where>
```

**Update**
Found out this is valid syntax in SPS2010 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff625761.aspx). Anyway, you should strip out the `Query` element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I will check..I have refered the below link for <In> element [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff625761.aspx)

Comment: I checked the query which you have suggested to me It works fine :)
but how can we use the <In> tag ??
Thanks a lot

Comment: Just use the query you started with, but remove the `<Query>` and `</Query>` fragments.

Comment: When I use the query by removing <Query> and </Query> getting following exception... System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range. at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemData WithCallback

Comment: If this is the Client Object Model you need to keep the `<Query>` tags but also add `<View>` and `</View>` around the query. Just for completeness in case some one stumbles across this while searching the Internet.

Comment: Good point, Robert! The same is true, if this query is used via lists.asmx web service!